# Archer GRC: Calculate number days between two date fields

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

When my values list *Respondent Status* changes to “Completed” I need to  Calculate the number days between *Date Initiated* (date field) and *Respondent Status Date Change* (date field).

```
IF([Respondent Status ] = VALUEOF("Completed"),
DATEDIF([Date Initiated ], [Respondent Status Date Change], DAY),
```

How do I account for it the value isn't Completed? Something with true or false statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the field itself (and it will retain the current value) or a static value.

```
IF([Respondent Status] = VALUEOF([Respondent Status],"Completed"),
DATEDIF([Date Initiated], [Respondent Status Date Change], DAY),
[FIELD])

IF([Respondent Status] = VALUEOF([Respondent Status],"Completed"),
DATEDIF([Date Initiated], [Respondent Status Date Change], DAY),
0)
```

Comment: I took out the name of the field part to get my answer, I didn't need it in my calculation I've found. I'll edit yours and accept it.

Comment: DIdn't see those VALUEOF nice spot!